# How to run robocopy batch script on remote computer via WMI

Tags: batch-file, cmd, remote-access, robocopy, wmic

I am trying to run a script(called testScript.bat) on a remote computer.
The script is:

```
mkdir D:\someFolderPath\batchActivatedTestDir
ROBOCOPY "\\Computer1\D\Drivers" "\\Computer2\D\User\Desktop\DestinationTest" /E
```

I tested the script and it works fine when I double click it on the remote machine.

Now I am trying to run it via WMI command:

```
wmic /user:User /password:"Password" /node:Computer2 process call create
     "d:\scriptLocationPath\testScript.bat"
```

Now I get the usual success message in my cmd on computer1:

```
Executing (Win32_Process)->Create()
Method execution successful.
Out Parameters:
instance of __PARAMETERS
{
        ProcessId = 2028;
        ReturnValue = 0;
};
```

But as I learned it refers to the excution of WMI command.

**The result of the WMI command** above is that the directory: "batchActivatedTestDir" is created but robocopy is not starting.

I don't even see the process ROBOCOPY.exe in task manager.  Why is it not working properly, if the batch is activated ?

Even if I try to activate robocopy directly like this:

```
wmic /user:User /password:"12345678" /node:Shimon process call create  
    "ROBOCOPY.exe \\DavidPC\D\drivers d:\User\Desktop\destination1\test /E"
```

I get to see the process "ROBOCOPY.exe" in the task manager for a second and then it's gone :(

I don't understand why robocopy refuses to be activated.
Please help.